# Mobile Web URL, is this coming from Heroku or do I need to get my own hosting service for my mobile web app?

Tags: facebook, html, extjs

In the Apps creation page on facebook I have to enter a MObile Web URL, does this mean that I have to host my HTML5 mobile web app in an externally hosted service? like Amazon, or Azure? 
I know that HEroku is offered as a cloud service but it only supports Ruby, PHP, Python. But I want to use Sencha to create my HTML5 mobile web app , and include facebook JavaScript SDK in it. So, does this mean that I need to host my HTML5 app in an external host service and enter that URL as the Mobile Web URL in the Facebook App creation page?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can build your mobile web app using any language or framework you choose. You do need to host it on an external service, like Amazon, Azure - or Heroku, which can support any number of server-side languages as you mentioned.

Take a look at our mobile web tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/